# In Clojure, can the result of an expression be the first argument to a (def)?

Tags: clojure, compiler-errors, macros, lisp

My ultimate goal is to produce this code with a macro, where word can be any string (without white space):

```
=> (def word "word")
```

This is what I have so far. It compiles, but doesn't run.

```
=> (defmacro mirror [val] `(def (symbol val) val))
```

Expected behavior:

```
=> (mirror "michael")
=> (mirror "jackson")
=> michael
"michael"
=> jackson
"jackson"
```

Actual behavior:

```
=> (mirror "michael")

Syntax error compiling def at (/tmp/form-init2235651799765014686.clj:1:25).
First argument to def must be a Symbol
```

From what I understand, `(def)` is expecting a Symbol as it's first argument, which `(symbol val)` should return. My guess is that the compiler is checking `(def)`'s arguments' types before evaluating them, so instead of a Symbol it sees an expression and throws an error.

Comment: You can investigate the expansion with (macroexpand '(mirror "michael"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defmacro mirror [val] `(def ~(symbol val) ~val))
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually enable anything very interesting. The string provided to this macro must still be a compile-time constant, and so you can't write, e.g., `(def module-name "foo") (def foo-test "ok") (mirror (str module-name "-test"))`, which is the next thing people usually try when they want to generate a `def` form.

Answer (score 0):

If `val` is expected to be a string literal, akond's solution suffices.

If you want to use string-generating expressions, like amalloy does in his comment, you can write:

```
(defmacro mirror [exp] (let [val (eval exp)] `(def ~(symbol val) ~val)))
```

Using amalloy's example we have:

```
=> (def module-name "foo")
#'user/module-name
=> (mirror (str module-name "-test"))
#'user/foo-test
=> foo-test
"foo-test"
```

This macro evaluates the expression "at compile-time". This means among other things that you cannot use local variables inside it (e.g. `(let [suffix "-test"] (mirror (str module-name suffix)))` fails). To evaluate it "at run-time" you can write:

```
(defmacro mirror [exp] `(let [~'val ~exp] (eval `(def ~(symbol ~'val) ~~'val))))
```

Alternatively, you could avoid macros and `def` and use `intern`.